# Facebook API - Retrieving likes for URL

Tags: facebook, json, api, request, facebook-fql

I'm attempting to do this via FQL but I think I'm retrieving info from the wrong database or something.

Using this FB Like iframe to 'like' a URL:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://shop.sinkorswimbrand.com/product/sink-or-swim-snapback&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=46&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" onclick="javascript:updateLikes();" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:46px; height:21px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Using this FQL URL to retrieve JSON info on the URL:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count from link_stat where url='http://shop.sinkorswimbrand.com/product/sink-or-swim-snapback'&format=json
```

Returns: --- **Note: I've made sure to 'like' this myself.**

```
[{"total_count":0,"like_count":0,"comment_count":0,"share_count":0,"click_count":0}]
```

Does anyone with more experience with Facebook's API have any experience with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your og:meta tags. This tag on line 31 of your generated source:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sinkorswimbrand.com" />
```

This tells Facebook to aggregate all the likes for this page into the  `www.sinkorswimbrand.com` results.

You can see this if you look at the "Redirect Path" section of the [debugger results for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.sinkorswimbrand.com%2Fproduct%2Fsink-or-swim-snapback).

You need unique `og:url` tags for each page of your site if you want likes for each individual product page.

Also, you're using a deprecated url to make an FQL query. You should be using `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...`